# how do I call a variable in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I'm trying to call a variable from a table, but I'm getting an error "Undefined variable $user". I'm trying to make the program display the Username from the user from the table.

I'm using 2 tables, tribes which represents something like a group, and a user which represents.. well.. user.
So I'm trying to connect the two by displaying the creator of a certain "tribe".

User controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
Use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class tribesController extends Controller
{
    public function index($user)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($user);
         
        return view('home',[
            'user'=>$user,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Homepage:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Dashboard') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    {{ $user->username }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Router:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/home', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Route::get('/playlist', function () {
    return view('playlist');
});

Route::get('/tribe', function () {
    return view('tribe');
});


Route::get('/edit', function () {
    return view('edit');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/tribe/{user}', [App\Http\Controllers\TribesController::class, 'index'])->name('tribe.index');
```

Database file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateTribesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tribes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('genre');
            $table->string('filepath')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tribes');
    }
}
```

model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class tribe extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    use HasFactory;
}
```

Comment: In your controller, if you ``dd($user)`` after the findOrFail statement, what do you get? If ``null``, then there was no user returned and that is why it would be failing.

Comment: I added this to the router:

Route::get('/user', function () {
    dd($user);
});

then ran: http://127.0.0.1:8000/user
same error

but if I run 
Route::get('/user', function () {
    return dd(Auth::user()->tribe->title);
});

Comment: I meant to run that in your controller after the ``$user = User::findOrFail($user);`` line. That will show you exactly what the code is doing at that point. Otherwise we tend to assume that of course the query is returning exactly what we expect it to. Always try to output the variables when troubleshooting to see what exactly is stored in it.

Comment: I ran it like that, it lists all the info about the user, if I do it by an id where the user doesn't exist, it returns null, which I believe it should..

Comment: Excellent! Yes, it returns null if there is no user found with that id. Okay, so next up if you ``{{ dd($user) }}`` inside the Homepage, you can make sure that this is getting the data from the controller. If that works, make sure that the ``username`` field exists for that user. If that works, then you can see if ``$user->tribe->id`` works, assuming you have a ``tribes`` function in the User model with ``return $this->hasMany(Tribe::class)`` in it. Sorry... that's probably a lot of steps in one small comment.

Comment: Actually solved it myself, didn't actually solved it, just was using wrong pathing.. Didn't actually understand how it worked. Thank you for your help anyways :)

Comment: Hopefully I gave you some tips for how to troubleshoot Laravel. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are treating the url parameter as a object, it can't be an object until you get it. Pass in a  user id and then query the ORM for a user matching that id then you can use it as an object!